# SPI protocol implementation and delay

Tags: spi

From my understanding, SPI is implemented by using 2 shift registers, one at each device.
Shift registers are a serially connection of D-flipflops

If the same clock is used to transfer data from master to slave and from slave to master
If the clock signal is clocked at MSB on the master, the new data is racing towards the LSB on the slave device, so if the LSB flip flop does not receive a clock before the new data arrives its essentially overwritten.

Similarly if the clock reaches the MSB+1 faster than MSB on a shift register the data is overwritten at MSB reaching LSB at the salve device

How are these 2 problems solved? Im assuming maybe some buffers or a FIFO is used

In addition, when the clock frequency increases, for the first case if the clock line to LSB slave is faster than the data transfer essentially the MSB data is clocked twice at the LSB slave

How is this problem solved?

Or are any of these problems at all?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: You really need to take a step back and learn about synchronous system design. Using simple, common design practices eliminates these so-called problems.

Comment: Im just wondering if these are problems at all, because all of the videos ive seen show a simple shift register but in actually i believe the implementation could be more more complex

Comment: Didn't you just ask basically the same 2 hours ago?

Comment: Is it true that these are problems? I could read a book on how to solve synchronisation thats not the problem. Im analysing the circuit without any prior knowledge to circuit design

Comment: Kinda but they asked me to provide more detail

Comment: "Im analysing a circuit without any prior knowledge to circuit design" This is your problem. You need to stop watching videos and start reading.

Comment: SPI peripherals first started appearing about 40 years ago. Synchronous data transfer existed even before that. These problems are known or solved long ago.

Comment: The point is, analysis without prior knowledge is not a problem in any domain of thought. Its what leads development, here i'm simply asking whether these are actually problems

Comment: In a perfect world all flip flops would see the same clock at the same time, thus there would be no ‘ripple effect’ and you could use a clock of infinite speed. In the real world, everything takes a finite amount of time, so the actual clock edge each f/f sees is slightly different - so this limits the achievable system clock rate. Is it a problem? Yes. The solution comes down to synchronous logic design- calculating things like setup and hold times, propagation delays, clock skew etc.

Comment: @TechVisionary - Hi, Regarding your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/540403) and the request you mentioned, that "*they asked me to provide more detail*": The "Stack Exchange approach" is that a question should edited to add more detail, *not* asked in another question (hence they said to "amend your question"). This leaves your previous question as a sort of zombie, that won't get improved as you asked this new question. So now we have to "jump through some hoops" to get that one closed and deleted. FYI there are more site rules in the [tour] and [help]. Thanks.

Comment: @techvisionary Please edit questions instead of posting duplicate questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic SPI is *system synchronous*, that is, a single clock determines the timing origin for both outbound and returning signals.

SPI also specifies that signals launch on one edge (e.g., falling) and sampling on the other (e.g., rising). This is a way to ensure the data are stable during the sampling time. More generally, the SPI data needs to meet setup and hold time to the sampling edge to ensure reliable data capture.

As the clock rate increases, a problem arises called *turn around time*: the total delay from clock launch, through the endpoint, then back to the master eats up the read data setup time at the master. This affects SPI reads and can severely limit the achievable clock speed.

Careful design of the slave’s read data shift register and clock tree can reduce this, but there will always be trace delay, clock delay and clock-to-Q added to the read data.

Unfortunately, by specifying launch-on-opposite edge, the SPI protocol just makes the turnaround issue worse: the half-cycle delay eats up even more of the read data setup time.

It’s actually better to specify a setup/hold and design your timing to that, with read data launched on the rising edge. Then the entire cycle can be used to propagate the read data and thus relax the setup time.

Another alternative is to synthesize a clock at the slave that compensates for the turn around time, using a delay-lock loop. Or, if the master and slave share a common reference they can synthesize local copies of the SPI clock.

Some fast SPI implementations introduce a DQS return strobe alongside the data that has similar timing. This approach is called *source synchronous*, and is the same technique used for DRAM, Ethernet MAC-PHY and some fast digital interfaces like SDIO.

Comment: Thank you but what i want to understand is, when the clock is rising edge on the Master and Slave do all flip-flops change state at the same time. Given that they are different distances from the clock

Comment: No, they don’t. The slave side inserts clock input delay and clock-to-Q. Also, there is the trace delay between master and slave, and for read data this is doubled as it is round-trip. This is the basic problem with system sync.

Comment: Can you recommend any books for me?

Comment: Appreciate your replies btw, informative

Comment: Also what is shifting and sampling? Is shifting ou of the master and sampling in from the slave?

Comment: Google source synchronous timing. As for shifting and sampling, generally think in terms of clock-to-output, and input setup time.

Answer (score 0):

In SPI, the shift will be done for example in the falling edge, and the sampling is done in the rising edge (depending on the configuration).
[image: SPI communication]

From here - [SPI tutorial](https://www.corelis.com/education/tutorials/spi-tutorial/)

Comment: You are not actually answering the question that was asked.